# How to express “<imperative> or <imperative>”?

Tags: verbs, grammar, imperatives

I want to express the structure “A or B”, where A and B are verbs in the imperative mood. The specific example I want to say is “Stand and rot or fall apart right now.”

I assume just saying 「立って朽ちろか今すぐバラバラになれなぁ」won’t work as か is used for alternatives with nouns.

Is there a structure that I could use here?

Comment: か is also used to indicate alternative options for verbs. Example: [「行くか残るか」](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F%E3%81%8B%E6%AE%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%22), among infinite many other potential combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to split the sentence into two and use a conjunctive such as [さもなくば](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%84%B6%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%B0) (literary/theatrical), [あるいは](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%88%96%E3%81%84%E3%81%AF) (formal) or それか (colloquial). Another approach is to use AかB(か) with plain form verbs and then add 選べ or 決めろ at the end of the sentence.

- ここで朽ち果てろ。さもなくば今すぐここでバラバラになれ。
- ただここで朽ち果てるか、今すぐバラバラになるか、好きな方を選べ。